# Принцип работы, методов клиент-сервер?

Tags: reactjs, express, клиент-сервер

Не до конца понимаю как отправлять запрос на сервер и как его получать и обрабатывать(react.js & express) | как понять в каком форме запрос отправляется...

1. Я так понимаю нужно почитать про HTTP-протокол? Или API ? В какую сторону копать...
2. Есть ли источники, где самая актуальная инфа по данному направлению?

Comment: fetch, ajax, XMLHttpRequest, Axios etc

Comment: см: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFyFoLYZnz8 там использован WebSocket и довольно подробно описано взаимодействие с сервером; (проматывай моменты которые тебя не интересуют)